# Data reconciliation between 2 datasets on SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, database-reconciliation, reconcile

[image_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BS5K.png)

I currently need to find all the differences between a new_master dataset and a previous one using SQL Oracle. The datasets have the same structure and consist of both integers and strings and do not have a unique key id unless I select several columns together. You can see an image at the beginning as image_table. I found online this code and I wanted to ask you if you have any advices.

```
SELECT n.*
FROM new_master as n
LEFT JOIN old_master as o
ON (n.postcode = o.postcode)
WHERE o.postcode IS NULL
SORT BY postcode
```

In doing so I should get back all the entries from the new_master that are not in the old one.

Thanks

Comment: `SORT BY` not exists, use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: *find all the differences between a new_master dataset and a previous one* Does these two datasets means 2 different tables each with a dataset, or you mean a subsets from the same table? And specify your MySQL version - it is important.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: MYSQL or ORACLE or both?

Comment: Hi all,

I added an image of the table at the beginning as image_table, the datasets are in structure the same but 2 different years and I need to check the differences. It' Oracle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an Oracle databse, there are a couple queries that can help you find any differences.

Find any records in OLD that are not in NEW.

```
SELECT * FROM old_master
MINUS
SELECT * FROM new_master;
```

Find any records in NEW that are not in OLD.

```
SELECT * FROM new_master
MINUS
SELECT * FROM old_master;
```

Count number of items in OLD

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM old_master;
```

Count number of items in NEW

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM new_master;
```

The `COUNT` queries are needed in addition to the `MINUS` queries in case there are duplicate rows with the same column data.

Comment: You should point out that this is an oracle answer, minus does not exist in mysql.

Comment: Nice catch. Added note for Oracle.